# xboxdrv apparently blocked xbox controller

Tags: usb, games, udev, xbox-360

I own a Gioteck VX4PS4-34-MU XBox Controller and it was recognized by Ubuntu 22.10:

```
$ lsusb | grep Xbox360
Bus 005 Device 007: ID 045e:028e Microsoft Corp. Xbox360 Controller

$ ls -l /dev/input/js*
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root input 13, 0 apr 10 17:17 /dev/input/js0
```

and added my user to `input` group:

```
$ groups
mark adm dialout cdrom sudo dip video plugdev input render lpadmin lxd sambashare
```

I checked it worked fine using `evtest-qt` or even with `cat /dev/input/js0`.
But the games didn't find any suitable controller.

Hence, after reading through tutorials and threads I found I need to install `xboxdrv` in order to expose a compatible device to applications.

I added this `udev` rules in order to get the USB access as regular user:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="045e",   ATTRS{idProduct}=="028e", OWNER="root", GROUP="plugdev", TAG+="uaccess"
```

and some games finally listed the controller, but without any movements or trigger.
Coming back to the beginning, now `cat` or `evtest-qt` do the same: the event file is there but no more inputs from the device.

I tried to remove the `udev` rule and purge the `xboxdrv` package, but still no more input.

What was my mistake? How could I recover the situation?